# Как сделать блоку фон в виде трапеции?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой бэкграунд
[image]

Вставлять картинкой не хочется. Как лучше сделать его на css?

Comment: [Статья](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms), как задавать блокам трапециевидный фон, [пример](http://codepen.io/jeremyfrank/pen/qOXeWL). Правда, в ней рассматриваются прямоугольные и тупоугольные трапеции, а автору нужен фон в виде остроугольной. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

А вам кроссбраузерно или как?)

Можете использовать clip-path ( очень нравится эта штука )
[Вот генератор](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)
Можете поиграться с rotate ( но кода будет [побольше](http://jsbin.com/yimehuwefa/edit?css,output) )

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 190px;
  top: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap:before,
.wrap:after {
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  height: 50px;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(9deg)
}
.wrap:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(3deg)
}
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='block'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

clip-path посоветовали, а т.к. всё это шаманство родом из svg, несколько кликов в векторном редакторе и навскидку

```css
#rect1,
#rect2,
#rect3,
#rect4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 97vw;
  height: calc(97vw * 0.5);
  margin-top: 10%;
}
#rect1:before,
#rect3:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#rect1:before {
  background-color: black;
  transform: matrix(0.9901338, 0.14012513, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  height: 75%;
}
#rect3:before {
  background: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDYyMiAzMDEiPgogIDxnIGlkPSJwYXJsIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSgtNTcuNzg2IC0zNTkuMDQpIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Im01Ny43ODYgMzU5LjA0IDYyMi4yMyA5NS43MyAwLjQ0IDIwNS44MS02MjIuMjItNDcuMDJ6IiBmaWxsPSIjMDAwIi8+CiAgPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4=") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 100% auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#canvas {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>1. <b>css transform</b> - противополжные стороны равны</p>
<div id="rect1"></div>

<p>2. <b>inline svg</b> - один из вариантов использования</p>
<div id="rect2">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 622 301">
    <use xlink:href="#prl"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
<p>2. <b>css base64 background</b> - <a href="http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php">кодирование svg</a>
</p>
<div id="rect3"></div>

<p>4. <b>canvas</b>
</p>
<div id="rect4">
  <canvas id='canvas' width='622' height='301'></canvas>
</div>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

  // #layer1
  ctx.save();
  ctx.transform(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -57.785973, -359.036760);

  // #path4155
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
  ctx.lineCap = 'butt';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1.000000;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
  ctx.moveTo(57.785973, 359.036760);
  ctx.lineTo(680.021990, 454.765370);
  ctx.lineTo(680.457100, 660.581900);
  ctx.lineTo(58.244903, 613.558210);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
</script>



<!-- исходник svg -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 622 301" style="position:fixed;">
  <g id="prl" transform="translate(-57.786 -359.04)">
    <path d="m57.786 359.04 622.23 95.73 0.44 205.81-622.22-47.02z" fill="#000" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

К предложенным выше, добавлю вариант с помощью border. На мой вкус, самый простой)

Фигуры на CSS: https://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/

```css
.block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
.wrap {
  width:500px;
  background-color: grey;  
  position: relative;  
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 60px;
}
/* верхний скос */
.wrap::before {  
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-left: 500px solid #333;  
  top: -45px;
}
/* нижний скос */
.wrap::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 500px solid #333;
  bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html {
  height: 400px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(10deg, transparent 0, transparent 35%, silver 35%, silver 65%, transparent 65%, transparent 100%),
    linear-gradient( 5deg, transparent 0, transparent 25%, silver 25%, silver 55%, transparent 55%, transparent 100%),
    white;
}
```