# Как сделать скошенные углы у блока

Tags: css, css3

Доброго времени суток.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такие углы у блока, я знаю вариант с псевдоэлементами before и after, может есть вариант получше?
Мое решение:

```
.block {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        transform: rotate(1deg);
        top: -30px;
        background: #FFF; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Напишите варианты с `:before` и `:after` в качестве ответа на свой вопрос, не стесняйтесь :)

Comment: Нарисовать фоновую картинку для блока, а потом `background: url('bg-image.png') right center no-repeat transparent`

Comment: По ощущению, тут можно сделать перспективу и чуть повернуть прямоугольник вокруг вертикальной оси. Не претендую на решение, т. к. реализовать это сходу не смогу :}

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как стилизовать такой элемент?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442284/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82)

Comment: Вопрос похож да, но по-моему не дубликат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может такой вариант подойдет, хотя и не самый удобный. С помощью  transform: skewY.

```css
#outer,
#block,
#outer2,
#block2 {
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}
#content {
  transform: skewY(3deg);
  padding: 30px 20px 60px 20px;
}
#block {
  background: blue;
  transform: skewY(1deg);
}
#outer {
  background: red;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  transform: skewY(-4deg);
}
#content2 {
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  padding: 30px 20px;
}
#block2 {
  background: #c1c1c1;
  transform: skewY(1deg);
}
#outer2 {
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: orange;
  padding-top: 4px;
  transform: skewY(4deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="block">
    <div id="content">
      Any text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="outer2">
  <div id="block2">
    <div id="content2">
      Any text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Скажите кроссбраузерность страдает от такого метода?

Comment: Это свойство относится к CSS3, и поддерживается всеми современными браузерами. С более старыми версиями конечно могут быть проблемы.

Comment: Зато красиво деградирует.

Answer (score 1):

Имхо, подобные углы проще всего сделать именно картинкой. Парочка прозрачных png, может быть отлично оптимизирована через https://tinypng.com/ до 16-32 цветов, что в общем итоге даст 3-4 кб на обе картинки. Далее, при сборке, эти картинки можно будет [конвертировать](https://github.com/ehynds/grunt-image-embed) в Base-64 и всё.

Comment: Хмм...ну я больше ищу ответ как правильнее делать, а не быстрее)

Comment: Это и будет правильней в вашем случае, и еще годик-другой имхо. Протестируйте первое решение в разных браузерах и вы увидите, что сглаживание этих линий как то не очень, не дотягивает где-то до фотошопного качества, так что рановато имхо. Вот если бы угол был побольше, то да.

Comment: Та вот и переживаю насчет первого решения, что не везде пойдет. Так что буду все пробовать. Спасибо)