# Разделить фон по диагонали на Bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Возник вопрос, возможно покажется глупым
Необходимо разделить фон главной страницы на две части. Два изображения приложил к записи. Разделить именно так как на эскизе. Сетка Bootstrap
Вопрос в том, что они не квадратные(вернее квадратные, но часть которая за диагональю без фона). 
Правая часть - слайдер. Левая просто картинка. 
Не понимаю как их разместить...пробовал уже по разному. Нужно именно на бутстрап, им пользовался довольно редко..

Буду бесконечно благодарен за любую помощь!
[image: Итог]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, ну я так понимаю можно будет стилизовать, чтоб было впритык ?

Comment: Нужен обязательно бутстрап

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Вот так**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <style> 
           .container{
            width:100%;
            position: relative;
           }
           .container:after{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
            background: linear-gradient(-51deg, transparent 63%, #AF9CFF 0);
           }
           img{
            width:100%;
            max-height: 100%
           }

   </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
   <img src="http://classpic.ru/wp-content/uploads/Devushka-v-golubom-plate.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"> 
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: круто, большое спасибо)))

Comment: автор не я, а `Vlad Teryoshin`

Answer (score 2):

```
background-image: url(images/bg.jpg); /* Путь к фоновому изображению */
background-color: #f3f3f3;
```

Вот и все... А вот тут еще больше информации по этому поводу [ТУТ](https://webref.ru/css/background).

Comment: Я понимаю как задать фон и фоновое изображение ) вопрос как реализовать конкретный эскиз на бутстрап

Comment: @Vlad Teryoshin, а разве не подойдет такое решение для бутстрапа?

Comment: Как их диагонально разделить на сетке бутстрап, в этом вопрос (( все равно благодарен за ответ, но все же вопрос открыт

Comment: может сделать два дива рядом , со скошенными рядом диагоналями , в один поместить картинку а во второй - слаидер  
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443358

Comment: @Vlad Teryoshin, поиграйте с `background-size`, но я даже не могу представить, как это под сетку подставить одним блоком, но двумя вполне реально, но это нужно будет на них все набрасывать

Comment: Так вот проблема в том , что я умею не на бутстрапе)) спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Vlad Teryoshin, а попробуйте немного по другому подойти к этому, создав два блока с этими фонами, а на них уже блок с содержимым налаживать... только блок с содержимым должен быть с абсолютным позиционированием.

Comment: В любом случае там будет содержимое, я его не включал сюда просто . Два блока у меня получились, вот только диагональ эта нет , пустое место между ними выходит. Я вот думал сначала слайдер добавить а потом абсолютно позиционировать блок который слева, он отбрежет слайдер. Но это неправильно..так как есть ещё меню, которое тоже необходимо будет позиционировать абсолютно